# Access custom component methods through ref doesnt work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone explain to me why in `SomeClass` constructor `getLoggerClass` method returns undefined,but inside `onClick()` method it returns logger class?

```js
class App extends React.Component {

 constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.getLoggerClass = this.getLoggerClass.bind(this)
 }
 
  render(){
  
   return(
   
    <div>
      <LoggerClass ref={(c)=>{this.loggerClass = c}}/>
      <SomeClass app={this} />
    </div>
   
   ) 
  
  }
  
  getLoggerClass(){
    return this.loggerClass
  
  }

}

class SomeClass extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props){
  super(props)

    this.loggerClass = this.props.app.getLoggerClass()
    console.log(this.loggerClass)
    
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)
  }
  
  render(){
  
   return <button onClick={this.onClick}>click</button>
  
  }
  
  onClick(){

    console.log(this.props.app.getLoggerClass().console)
    
  }

}

class LoggerClass extends React.Component {

  render(){
    return <div></div>
  }
  
  console(v){
    console.log(v)
  }
  
  test(){}

}


ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `ref` function on the `LoggerClass` node hasn't been executed by the time the `constructor` of `SomeClass` gets run. The `constructor` gets executed when creating the virtual DOM, whereas the `ref` gets executed when the component actually gets mounted to the real DOM ([more info about mounting here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556450/what-is-mounting-in-react-js)). Here's what I think you're looking for, with the relevant code in `SomeClass`'s `componentDidMount`:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

 constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.getLoggerClass = this.getLoggerClass.bind(this)
 }
 
  render(){
  
   return(
   
    <div>
      <LoggerClass ref={(c)=>{this.loggerClass = c}}/>
      <SomeClass app={this} />
    </div>
   
   ) 
  
  }
  
  getLoggerClass(){
    return this.loggerClass
  
  }

}

class SomeClass extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props){
  super(props)
    
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loggerClass = this.props.app.getLoggerClass()
    console.log('in mounted', this.loggerClass.console)
  }
  
  render(){
  
   return <button onClick={this.onClick}>click</button>
  
  }
  
  onClick(){

    console.log(this.props.app.getLoggerClass().console)
    
  }

}

class LoggerClass extends React.Component {

  render(){
    return <div></div>
  }
  
  console(v){
    console.log(v)
  }
  
  test(){}

}


ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the culprit :

```
constructor(props){
super(props)

this.loggerClass = this.props.app.getLoggerClass()
console.log(this.loggerClass)

this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)
}
```

To understand the problem you must understand the, quote mdn, [The constructor method is a special method for creating and initializing an object created within a class.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor)

So basically, this constructor method is used to initialize, and so it is called only one time during the class life. So when your `SomeClass` first renders, the `constructor`method is called and in it you define : this.loggerClass as this.props.app.getLoggerClass() (notice here that you called the function immediately at init time) so what is happening is that :

- first constructor() is called
- in it you called **directly** the getLoggerClass() method, this method returns the dom node but at init time it is `undefined`

Try to not call the getLoggerClass method directly but call it later, you do not need to bind it though, just declare in your SomeClass component a method that just calls the getLoggerClass method like so :

```
callGetLoggerClassFromProps() {
  return this.props.app.getLoggerCLass()
}
```

this way you give the time to the ref to be assigned.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation,the way @Zevgon solve this problem using `componentDidMount` is a nice way.