# React Native Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I keep getting this error in React Native and I have not found a solution yet after a few hours.

> Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the myEnabled component.

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = { enabled: true };
        this.setEnabled = this.setEnabled.bind(this);
    }

    setEnabled(value){
        this.setState({ enabled: value });
    }

    getState(){
        return this.state.enabled;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162522/cant-call-setstate-on-a-component-that-is-not-yet-mounted)

Comment: you should learn about react's lifecycle methods; [React lifecycle](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)