# When react unmount and remount child component if parent component updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My code looks like

```
@connect((store)=>{
    return{        
        obj:store.obj
    }
})
class ParentComponent extends React.Component{ 
     render(){
            return(
                   <ChildComponent/>   
             )
      }        
}
```

Store change is causing re-rendering of `ParentComponent` which is fine. But the issue is, it's triggering `componentDidMount` in `ChildComponent` each time the `ParentComponent` is re-rendering. I am really not sure what I am missing here.
NOTE: The issue is reproducible only in react production build. Working fine in React Dev build.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "Mounting" in React js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556450/what-is-mounting-in-react-js)

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same problem. I don't think it's a duplicate of the above.