# Incorrect function of 2 chained buttons in Dash app

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Having the dash app layout example allows me to export 2 DataTables in Excel. First, it requires an excipient value submitted by pressing a "Submit" button, then it is possible to use the "Export" button. All working great.
However, if I change the excipient value after I already exported the tables (aka fired the Export button), the datatables are downloaded with firing the "Submit" button! Meaning that in a 2nd cycle of using the Dash app, the Submit button works as Export button, too, which is wrong.
How can that be handled? I tried to implement the app.clientside_callback as shown here: [Plotly Dash: Download getting triggered automatically after removing element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69974212/plotly-dash-download-getting-triggered-automatically-after-removing-element) but without success since it should work only in single callback scope.
Thank you for suggestions.

```
import dash
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, dash_table
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash import dash_table 


# simplified Dash app. layout:
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.H1("CLUSTER ANALYSIS"),
        html.H2("Enter 1 or multiple values, then press 'Submit'.",
               style = {'color': 'black', 'fontSize': 17}),
        dcc.Input(id = 'excipient',type = 'text') 
        html.Br(),
        html.Button(id = "submit-button", n_clicks = 0, children = 'Submit'),
    ]),
    
    html.Br(),
    
    html.Div([dcc.Graph(figure1]),
    
    
   html.Div([
        html.Div([table1]),
        html.Br(),
   ]),
    html.Div([
        html.Button(id = "export-button", children = 'Export'),
        html.Br(),
    ]),
    
    html.Div([
        dcc.Download(id = 'download_component'),
    ]),
    html.Div([
        html.Div([table2]),
       ]),
    ])

@app.callback(
    Output('figure1', 'figure'),
    Output("table1", "data"),
    Output("table2", "data"),
    Input('submit-button', 'n_clicks'),
    Input('table1', 'selected_rows'),
    State('excipient', 'value'),
    prevent_initial_call = True)

def update_function(n_clicks, selected_rows, excipient)
      # updates tables



@app.callback(
    Output('download_component', "data"),
    Input('export-button', 'n_clicks'),
    Input("table1", "data"),
    Input("table2", "data"),
    prevent_initial_call = True)

def export_function(n_clicks, data1, data2):
      # saves tables as .xlsx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shared the logic for your `export_function` callback, but I bet you have something like this:

```py
if n_clicks:
   # perform download action
```

What happens is, because your data inputs are causing this callback to fire, the `n_clicks` value is always truthy after the first run, so it always downloads.

The fix is to make your data inputs `State` and not `Input`, so that the callback only fires when the user clicks the button to download.

Comment: It goes like: `if n_clicks is not None:` #format the Excel file and export it.

Comment: You were right! I changed the very last 2 `Inputs` to `State` and works perfectly! Thanks!